# How to change order of values in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I want to edit arrangement of values entered in a column and separated by a semicolon.
For example this is a very small sample of my files:
[image]

And now i want to convert to this:
[image]

**Note:**

1. Always the first values from the left are the name of the year or part of the year or the year plus the month
2. Always the middle values placed between two semicolons are the desired names
3. After the conversion, the order of the names is not important, but the number related to the name should be placed on the name and below the desired year
4. After conversion, the order of years is important and must be sorted from small to large and from left to right. Note that the type of years may be different, for example (2000 Q1,Q1 2000,April 2000,2000 Apr,2000 April,Apr 2000,Mar 2005) all of this types or other types must sort.
5. This is only a very small sample of my 500 or 600 files.

I put this example here:

```
1998 Q4,Name1,17.33
1978 Q2,Name7,8.28
1988 Q2,Name2,4.7
1998 Q4,Name3,15.29
2020 Q3,Name6,5.5
1988 Q2,Name5,3.49
2020 Q3,Name4,4.41
2020 Q3,Name5,3.76
1978 Q2,Name2,12.53
1978 Q2,Name6,9.04
2020 Q3,Name7,3.65
1998 Q4,Name2,15.27
2020 Q3,Name8,2.74
2001 Q2,Name1,15.86
2001 Q2,Name4,12.33
2001 Q2,Name7,10.28
2001 Q2,Name3,9.77
1978 Q2,Name5,24.09
1978 Q2,Name1,15.22
1978 Q2,Name8,5.85
1988 Q2,Name1,4.79
```

Which script can help me? **This work cannot be done manually and it cannot be done quickly for a file with 500 cells containing values**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Using Text-to-Columns feature, you can first get your data into 3 distinct columns. It's delimited, so that's easy.

**Step 2:** Take your Column 1 data (Year Quarter) and copy/paste into another column and then remove duplicates. Then sort it, and then copy/paste transform to get those data left to right (Columns F to J in screenshot below). *Of course this could be tricky if your year data are messy. You may need a helper column or two in order to get this to correctly sort.*

**Step 3:** Take your Names data and the remove duplicates. Then sort it and place in the appropriate area (Column E in screenshot below).

**Step 4:** Input this formula into cell F2, which is a SUMIFS formula that sums column C when the Name and Time Period match.

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,F$1,$B:$B,$E2)
```

Drag it across and down, and you're done.

[image]

Comment: Or **Step 2**: Add row with column headers *and* **Step 3**: Use [**Pivot Table**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

Comment: @JohnSUN Yeah, wasn't sure if a pivot would work well here since the OP mentioned that year data are messy and needs it sorted. Perhaps if a 4th column with formatted date were created, then it would be an ideal solution. But not enough info was supplied to determine how messy these data are.

Comment: tnq very much - Can you record tutorial video for this 4 step and send to me? (I am extremely beginner and dumb in Excel)

Comment: I don't have that capacity. But shouldn't take long to look up these various items. Search for: (1) Split data using text to columns in Excel; (2) Removing duplicates in Excel; (3) Locking references in formulas (what those $ signs mean based on where they are).